# Pause Twitter Bootstrap Tabs on Hover

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap

I got the twitter bootstrap tabs to change on a timed sequence. I just want them to stop when I hover over them. Here is an example of them changing on a timed sequence...

http://library.buffalo.edu/index-km.html

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is that thing on your page ?

Comment: It's the large banner with the images. If you wait a few seconds you'll see the carousel change. I added an image to the question.

Comment: why don't you use carousel, http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel, instead of tabs

Comment: Didn't work for what I wanted. Adding thumbnails etc.

Comment: Do you ever have chance to check my updated answer ? It is easy to have thumbnails as navigation button.

Answer (score 0):

I built something like you want here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/Vje9U/6/). Let me know if this is what you want.

update note: put css on it to make it look nicer